# Search symbols in specific dependency IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bukkit

I have a library that I know roughly how it works, but I can't remember which class of the API I need to register events dynamically.

I can imagine a way to search a specific dependency, for a specific method/symbol. like ctrl alt n.

Is there a way to filter it to a specific jar/library/dependency, rather then it searching *all* libraries on the classpath?

Comment: For searching on classpath use `Strg + Shift + N`, however if you want to register and event using bukkit/spigot there is an good documentation online: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/using-the-event-api/

Comment: Googling suggests strg is ctrl in English, from german.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, add a **scope** first, then you can use this scope to filter the result.

The symbol search interface is as follows, the **scope filter** is in the upper right corner, the default value is `All Places`.

[image: Default symbols searching]

To add a custom **scope**, you need to do it in the settings, see the [help documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html).

After adding the **scope**, you can use the scope for filtering.

[image: use the scope for filtering]